# ASP.NET mail attachment inline

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line of code that creates an attachment.

```
email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(filebytes), "QRCode.png"));
```

now I am trying to apply ContentDisposition.Inline property to it....how would I do this when creating my attachment the way I did it?

Comment: Do you need solution in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want a solution in one line, this is one way of doing it:

```
email.Attachments.Add((new Func<Stream, Attachment>(stream => { var attachment = new Attachment(stream, "QRCode.png"); attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true; return attachment; }).Invoke(new MemoryStream(fileBytes))));
```

However, I **strongly discourage** this approach, it is awfully hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

@darjan-bogdan's solution would be the way to go if it **absolutely** needs to be one line for some reason.

However, if the goal is to just have a single-line logic statement for adding an attachment, I'd just use a helper method, à la:

```
Attachment data = BuildAttachment(new MemoryStream(filebytes), "QRCode.png"));
...

private Attachment BuildAttachment(MemoryStream stream, string name) {
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, name);
    attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;

    return attachment;
}
```

This preserves your "single line" in what I assume is your for-loop.

Comment: I agree with you, code should be readable.